# Inset automatically all child classes' instances into Dictionary

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a father class with many child classes, and I want to have an Dictionary with all the child classes already initialized.

I found a way to get all of the class types of the child classes but I didn't see how can it be helpful for me.

In the following exmaple I would like that all the pets will be in the dictionary automaticlly without the need to initialize every pet that I will make.

```
class pet
{
    public static Dictionary<string, pet> pets = new Dictionary<string, pet>();
    protected string name;

    public pet(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        pets.Add(name,this);
    }
}

class dog : pet
{
    public dog():base("Dog")
    {
    }
}

class cat : pet
{
    public cat():base("Cat")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want this to be completely dynamic? That is, if you add a new child class you don't have to change any code for it to create an instance of that new class?

Comment: It would be great if it would be dynamic.

Comment: DO you mean to initialize an object of each derived type inside the dictionary? If so, you can invoke the constructor found using reflection and insert into a dictionary with the Type as the key

Comment: No, I want it to be already invoked, the dictionary's key is a string that I construct every time I create a child class and the value is the initialized class.

Comment: An instance of the initialized class? Do you mean each time you initialize an object of any of the derived types?  I think you'd have to show a ```little``` code or at least some psuedocode. I have a working method to insert into a dictionary  an instance of every derived type (ie an object in which the constructor has been called for each derived type)

Comment: Can't you just do `pets.Add(name, this)` in the constructor of `pet`?

Comment: Oh I forgot to add it to this example, I do add when I initialize the class but how do I initialize all the classes?

Comment: What do you mean "initialize all the classes"? You want to... generate a single instance of each subclass? If that's what you want, my next question is *why*? There's no good reason to want to do something like that. Your question still is not clear.

Comment: I'd recommend a factory pattern, if you create a pet of the same name the constructor will throw a `ArgumentException("An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.")`.  You have a chance to not throw an exception, which is preferred.

Comment: I'm learning a bit about game programming in mono and I'm trying to make screens for exmaple: options, credits, end, game...
So I made a parent class screen and some child classes that everytime I will present one of them, for this I want to take all of the screens that I have and get them into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're getting the list of types you need to instantiate so I'll include the way I'd do it and you can take it from there. The code below assumes all the classes you want to instantiate and the base class are in the currently executing assembly.

```
foreach( Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() )
{
    if( type.BaseType == typeof( pet ) )
    {
        pet aPet = Activator.CreateInstance( type ) as pet;
        // Now add aPet to your dictionary
    }
}
```